# Using BeautifulSoup in Python, how can I find text that comes after the closing tag of an element?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the release date of a game from Steam's store page.  The html that I'm working with is as follows:

```
<div class="details_block">
  <b>Title:</b> Total War™: ROME II - Emperor Edition<br>
  <b>Genre:</b> <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Strategy/?snr=1_5_9__408">Strategy</a><br>
  <b>Developer:</b>
  <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?developer=Creative%20Assembly&snr=1_5_9__408">Creative Assembly</a>
  <br>
  <b>Publisher:</b>
  <a href="http://store.steampowered.com/search/?publisher=SEGA">SEGA</a>       <br>
  <b>Release Date:</b> Sep 2, 2013<br>
</div>
```

Ultimately, my goal is to retrieve a number of values from this "details_block" div.  I tried extracting all br tags from this section of code with:

```
details_block = bsObj.find("div", class_="details_block")

                for br in details_block.findAll('br'):
                    br.extract()
```

Then I access each piece of data that I want individually.  I am a little stuck on the release date though.  I am trying to access it with find_next_sibling() but nothing is being found, presumably because find_next_sibling only grabs elements with tags:

```
releaseDatePattern = re.compile(r'Release Date:')
                print details_block.find('b', text=releaseDatePattern).find_next_sibling().text.strip()
```

However, before I had extracted all of the br tags, it WAS finding the value, but it was attaching a br tag to it, which I did not want.

Is there an effective way to grab the release date without assuming that the order of these details in the detail_block will stay in this order?

Comment: `br` tags are empty, which will make it hard for you. So don't search the `br` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find all the `b` tags in the block. Then iterate over each of the `b` tag and you should get the text as `b.next_sibling`.

Comment: To OP: `details_block.find('b', text=releaseDatePattern).next_sibling.strip()`